# Angular JS with PDFTron

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdftron

I am trying to get a blob as a URL but i get an error on this line :

```
xhr.send()
```

The error message is `angular.js:13920 Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.`

But in the code I am using `xhr.open('GET', blobValue)` as shown in my code here

```
                if(someBlobValue){
                    var viewerElement = $document[0].getElementById('viewer');
                    var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
                        path: 'lib',
                        pdftronServer: 'https://demo.pdftron.com' // remove
                    }, viewerElement);

                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
                    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

                    xhr.onload = function() {
                        var recoveredBlob = xhr.response;

                        var reader = new FileReader;

                        reader.readAsDataURL(recoveredBlob);
                    };

                    xhr.open('GET', someBlobValue);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
                    xhr.send(); //error here although its open?
                    //var file = new File([newValue], 'somefile.pdf');
                    myWebViewer.loadDocument(xhr.response, { filename: 'somefile.pdf'});
```

Currently i have the document as a blob but i am trying to load it to pdftron library and unfortunately i dont seem to find the `myWebViewer.getInstance().loadLocalFile` method in the DOM (its undefined).

Would appreciate any pointers as its the first time trying to use pdftron in the angularjs app.

**NOTE** : This is inside a directive.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just pass the URL directly to WebViewer? By using a single GET call you are blocking viewing until the entire PDF is downloaded. However, if you give the URL directly, WebViewer can potentially begin displaying the PDF before all the data is downloaded.

Comment: I do not have a URL thats my problem, i have a blob, if i had the URL it would be easy.

Comment: Can you provide us the content of the variable `someBlobValue`?

Comment: Second parameter of [open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open#Syntax) method is always URL, not the blob content you want to send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the DOM element containing WebViewer to trigger the ready event, for the ReaderControl instance, returned from getInstance(), to be defined.

For example:

```
$(viewerElement).on('ready', function() {
  myWebViewer.getInstance().loadLocalFile(someBlobValue);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

#### There is nothing wrong in your code logically,

- You just forgot to instantiate the XHR object over here `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;`.
- You can correct it by doing this `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`